# How child can get command line arguments from the parent in c language

Tags: c, parent-child

this is my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    pid_t child = fork();

    char * argument = argv[1];

    if (child < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
    } 
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        if (argument == "What")
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Yes i did it", 11);
        }
        else
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Something went wrong...", 23);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

every time i run it with `gcc example.c -o name` then run it with `./name What` but every time on the console is written `Something went wrong...`.
how could i gain access to my first command line argument.

Comment: C strings should be compared with `strcmp`

Comment: Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book

Comment: Not directly related, but `write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Yes i did it", 11);` is very fishy. What would you do if all of a sudden you decide to change the text to `"Wow, perfect, I really did it, isn't it great?"`?

Comment: Not only that. Another issue with `write` is that it doesn't guarantee to write all the bytes you ask it to write. Use `printf` instead.

Comment: @ikegami: That's not really an accurate objection ("`write` doesn't guarantee to write all the bytes you ask it to write").  Neither does `printf()`, which on a Unix system usually relies on `write()` to do the dirty work.  OTOH, the only times `write()` won't write all the bytes are when there are failures of some sort — no space left on the device, or a socket is closed, or a pipe has no reader left, or …  There are reasons to use `printf()` instead of `write()` — that isn't one of them.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, You are wrong. `write` will return prematurely when writing to a full pipe or socket. `printf` will block instead (although I don't know if that's guaranteed).

Comment: @ikegami: write blocks on a full pipe unless you've set `O_NONBLOCK`.  It's also covered under the `...` in my comment, and my basic point is still valid.

Comment: @jonathan: i don't think that is quite correct. If you `write` to a pipe which is not full but does not have capacity for the full write, you can get a partial write with no error (returning the number of bytes written), whether or not the FD is non-blocking. `printf` will restart the underlying `write` automatically.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, My comments still apply to sockets even if they don't for pipes.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing pointers. The pointer returned by `"What"` will obviously be different than the pointer to the parameter, so the check will always fail. Use `strcmp`.